# How to make a PyGObject app fit into the dock on macOS

Tags: python, macos, gtk, pygobject, dock

I have a PyGObject application I've been happily using for years on Linux.  It can be found at [https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/hcm/](https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/%7Estrombrg/hcm/)

It currently runs on macOS using a PyGObject from homebrew.

However, on macOS it does not stay in the dock after starting hosts+commands.  It stays in the dock while selecting hosts and commands, but disappears from the dock as soon as the commands are initiated on the hosts.

I googled for about an hour, went through the top four pages of hits on "pygobject mac dock" plus a couple of other search terms, but found next to nothing.  The closest I came to finding an answer was for C code, and it didn't say how to do it, it only said it was possible.

How can I make a PyGObject application stay in the dock when sort-of-finshed, and how can I make it pop back up when re-selected?

I'm using pygobject3 3.40.1 and macOS 11.4 Big Sur.

Thanks!